# Cannot change domain class property value in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am developing a **Grails 2.3.7** application and I'm having trouble changing a domain property with a select box. Every time I try to change the property and save, I get a `HibernateException: identifier of an instance of Ethnicity was altered from X to Y`. I don't want to change the ID of the ethnicity, I simply want to change the `ApplicationPerson`s ethnicity from one to another.

A few things to note:

1. I am using the same controller action to create AND update the person.
2. Setting `personInstance.ethnicity` to `null` right before `personInstance.properties = params` will make the save work, but I
   don't know why, and I don't want to do this for every association
   that I want to change.
3. I realize the domain model seems odd. It is a legacy DB that I cannot change.

Here are my domain classes:

```
class ApplicationPerson implements Serializable {
    Integer appId
    Integer applicationSequenceNumber
    String firstName
    String lastName
    Ethnicity ethnicity

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['appId', 'applicationSequenceNumber'],
           generator: 'assigned'
    }
}

class Ethnicity {
    String code
    String description

    static mapping = {
        id name: 'code', generator: 'assigned'
    }
}
```

Here is my `_form.gsp` to update the `Ethnicity` (I removed all the other properties that are saving just fine):

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: personInstance, 
                                     field: 'ethnicity', 'error')} ">
    <label for="ethnicity">Ethnicity</label>
    <g:select id="ethnicity" 
              name="ethnicity.code" 
              from="${Ethnicity.list()}" 
              optionKey="code" 
              value="${personInstance?.ethnicity?.code}" />
</div>
```

And lastly, my controller action that the form POSTs to:

```
def save() {
    Application app = applicationService.getCurrentApplication()

    // Find/Create and save Person
    ApplicationPerson personInstance = app.person
    if (!personInstance) {
        personInstance = 
            new ApplicationPerson(appId: app.id, 
                                  applicationSequenceNumber: app.sequenceNumber)
    }
    personInstance.properties = params

    if (!personInstance.validate()) {
        respond personInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    personInstance.save flush:true
    redirect action: 'list'
}
```

Comment: What is `aidm` in composite key?

Comment: do you use migration scripts? and how about auto creating the database after backing up ...?

Comment: It's not that simple, unfortunately. This is a legacy database of a university. I can't really change anything, just have to create an application on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the name in the `select` element from `ethnicity.code` to `personInstance.etnicity.code` as shown below:

```
<g:select id="ethnicity" 
          name="personInstance.ethnicity.code" 
          from="${Ethnicity.list()}" 
          optionKey="code" 
          value="${personInstance?.ethnicity?.code}" />
```

The name of selected option gets bound to `params` as key and the selected value as the 
`value` against the key. Using `ethnicity.code` would try to modify the primary key of an existing `ethnicity` instead of modifying the ethnicity of an application person.

**UPDATE**
Above change in name is optional (can be used in case you don't need `params` to be assigned as properties of domain class). Previous name `ethnicity.code` should work as well but below changes are also required in the controller action in order to set ethnicity:

```
//or use params.ethnicity.code
//if name is ethnicity.code
person.ethnicity = Ethnicity.load(params.personInstance.ethnicity.code)

//or use params if name is ethnicity.code
person.properties = params.personInstance
```

Load an existing `Ethnicity` based on the passed in `code` and then set it in `person` before setting properties.

The issue lies with `code` being the primary key of `Ethnicity`. If `Ethnicity` had a separate identity column (for example, the default Long `id`) then your exact implementation in question would work with the help of data binding. But since it is mentioned that you are working with legacy database, I suppose you won't be able to modify the tables to add another column for `id`. So your best bet will be to `load`(cheap compared to get, as row is loaded from hibernate cache) ethnicity from the passed in code and then set it to person.

You can also see try caching the Ethnicity domain if possible because that will be master data and a good candidate for caching.

Comment: I tried this and didn't have any luck. I didn't I also tried `name="applicationPerson.ethnicity.code"` without luck. :(

Comment: No, when I make that change it simply doesn't change the ethnicity of the person. Sort of like the databinding doesn't happen. I also find it strange that performing `personInstance.ethnicity = null` just before `personInstance.properties = params` makes everything work. Is it possible I have mapped my domain classes wrong? In the DB, the `Person` table has one `ethnicity_code` field that maps to `Ethnicity`...so I'm pretty sure I mapped it correctly

Comment: See my update, ethnicity has to be loaded and then set to `person`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will give that a shot in the morning. I was hoping to avoid adding additional dependencies to the controller and simply go with `person.properties = params`, but it looks like I won't get it that simple.

Comment: As I said if Ethnicity had a separate id column, everything would have worked as expected. :)

Comment: I gave it a shot. I am now getting the error `org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.company.Ethnicity. Expected: class java.lang.String, got class java.lang.Long`. Weird. I explicitly define the `id` as `code`, and `code` is a `String`.

Comment: I thought you cannot change your legacy tables. If you are using `id` then you have to change the `optionKey` etc accordingly in `select`.

Comment: Well, I am using `code` as the id. I'm saying that in `static mapping`, I'm specifying that the name of `id` is `code`.

Comment: I think you are not getting what I am trying to say. If `Ethnicity` had an id column which was Long, then whatever you have in your question would have worked. Since you are using `code` as the `id` for Ethnicity table, you have to follow as mentioned in the answer. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you. :) I genuinely wish that `id` could be a `Long`, but that's not the way we have it set up. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Using `load()` works as long as they pass in a `code` that is in the database already. One issue is that `ethnicity` is nullable, therefore if a `null` code is passed in then I get an `ObjectNotFoundException`. And if I use `get()` and they pass in `null` then I get `object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`.

Comment: You are populating the drop-down using `Ethnicity.list()`, do you expect anything else can be passed?

Comment: I apologize, I should have included `noSelection="['': 'None']"`, which is in the `g:select` tag. I removed it for brevity's sake. There is the possibility a person will simply decide to not submit an `Ethnicity`, which means that the above errors will occur.

Comment: Then do a null check for code coming from params before `load`. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Yep, looks like that is going to be what needs to happen. Thanks again for the help. Enjoy your 50+ reputation!